# HTTP request in Ubuntu

Tags: http, url, browser, ubuntu, request

i need to call a HTTP request in ubuntu how do i do it? I can't seem to find an answer around on how to to do it?

**How do run the following url without calling a browser like lynx to do it?**

```
http://www.smsggglobal.com/http-api.php?action=sendsms&user=asda&password=123123&&from=123123&to=1232&text=adsdad
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

in your command prompt, run the following:

```
curl http://www.smsggglobal.com/http-api.php?action=sendsms&user=asda&password=123123&&from=123123&to=1232&text=adsdad
```

the curl command executes an http request for a given url and parameters.

if you need to specify another HTTP method, `use curl -X <TYPE> <URL>`, like this:

```
curl -X POST http://www.smsggglobal.com/http-api.php?action=sendsms&user=asda&password=123123&&from=123123&to=1232&text=adsdad
```

curl documentation: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Answer (score 6):

to display the results:

```
curl http://www.smsggglobal.com/http-api.php?action=sendsms&user=asda&password=123123&&from=123123&to=1232&text=adsdad
```

or

to save the results as a file

```
wget http://www.smsggglobal.com/http-api.php?action=sendsms&user=asda&password=123123&&from=123123&to=1232&text=adsdad
```